# Archimedean Spiral Excel Chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying to reproduce this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXMU_IHk8vI
I was able to reproduce the iteration process that is update the x and y values after each calculation.
I have now 2 issues recreating the chart.

1/ I used a scatter plot which gives a gross depiction of what is shown in the video. How can have an almost similar reproduction?

2/ I used this VBA code, as well as several other alternatives, to refresh the chart after each calculation but it doesn't work.

In the video, this is how the values, for instance row 8, are computed:
A8: =($B8-$B$1)/$B$2 ---
C8: = B8 * COS($A8) ---
D8: = B8 * SIN($A8) and b in the equation (cell B2) is updated as =5/B4. B4 (video) being itself updated with the below VBA macro.

```
Sub update_Beta()

For i = 0 To 1000
Cells(3, 2).Value = Cells(3, 2) + WorksheetFunction.Pi() / 1000
Application.Calculate
'Application.Charts("Test").Refresh
Call UpdateCharts
Next

End Sub

Sub UpdateCharts()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Dim myChart As ChartObject
For Each myChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    myChart.Chart.Refresh
Next myChart
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Alan - an observation: In update charts you probably want the first `Application.ScreenUpdating` to be setting it to `false`.

How do the charts depend on `B3` (`Cells(3, 2)`) - thanks

Comment: @JohnnieL, yes sorry, in my Excel file B3 (dθ) corresponds to B4 in the video. I removed the value of c since it is equal to 1. In the video, this is how the values, for instance row 8, are computed: A8: =($B8-$B$1)/$B$2 C8: =B8*COS($A8) D8: =B8*SIN($A8) and b in the equation (cell B2) is updated as =5/B4. B4 (video) being itself updated with the VBA macro. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with the following.  I needed both DoEvents for it to work.  I don't know why it needed two of them.  Maybe someone more versed at this can say why.

```
Sub update_Beta()

    For i = 0 To 1000
        DoEvents
        Cells(3, 2).Value = Cells(3, 2) + WorksheetFunction.Pi() / 1000
        DoEvents
    Next i
End Sub
```